# what is the usage of name Property in HttpGet ( such as [HttpGet("/products2/{id}", Name = "Products_List")])

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

In asp.net core, I seen

```
[HttpGet("/products2/{id}", ***Name = "Products_List")]***
public IActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    return ControllerContext.MyDisplayRouteInfo(id);
}
```

what is the usage of name Property in HttpGet (such as`[HttpGet("/products2/{id}", Name = "Products_List")]`)

And, How Can I read/send a Multipart/form-data from/to an apiapicontroller/client?

Comment: if this answer is helpful, please mark this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it can be used like this. The second parameter of `Url.Link` is an object.
   `@Url.Link("Products_List", new { id = 1 })`
   Also this property `RouteUrl` can use it.
   `@Url.RouteUrl("Products_List",new { id=2})`

*About route name, this is the official introduction:*

> The route names give the route a logical name. The named route can be used for URL generation. Using a named route simplifies URL creation when the ordering of routes could make URL generation complicated. Route names must be unique application wide.

> Route names:

> - Have no impact on URL matching or handling of requests.
> - Are used only for URL generation.

2. If you send a Multipart/form-data. The apicontroller can get it with `FromForm`.

   ```
    [HttpGet("routepath")]
    public IActionResult get([FromForm]SampleModel model)
    {
        //...
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I found that can  be used to string uri = Url.Link(“ Products_List”, id = 1);

Is there Some one can give me more detailed  information?